# Function pointer

Tags: c

---

In my A.h file

```
Node RemoveString(Node (*)(char,Node));
Node Minimum(char, Node);
```

---

In my A.c file

```
Node Minimum(char type, Node node) {......}
Node RemoveString(Node(*Minimum)(char, Node)) {...}
```

---

In my B.h file

```
void Test_Function(Node (*)(char,Node));
```

---

In my B.c file

```
void Test_Function(Node(*Minimum)(char, Node)) {...}
```

---

In my Main.c

```
Test_Function(Node(*Minimum)(char, Node));//This line has error.
```

---

Node is defined in A.h
B.h  include "A.h"
Main.c include "B.h"

The compiler complains that error: expected expression before ‘Node’
Can anybody tell me why ?What i did wrong in this case?

Comment: Try `Test_Function(&Minimum);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call a function, you just use the name of the function rather than the complete definition again. So this line:

```
Test_Function(Node(*Minimum)(char, Node));
```

Should be:

```
Test_Function(&Minimum);
```

Of course you should also make sure that the functions Test_Function and Minimum are defined (i.e. files included) before this statement.

Comment: The `&` isn't even needed if you prefer.

Comment: It works well if I use this "Test_Function(&Minimum);" not this "Test_Function(Minimum);"

Comment: Hmmm... that's weird! I thought both should be fine. Which compiler are you using?!

Comment: I just made a simple sample and compiled it with GCC, and both expressions worked with me! I am on Linux/Ubuntu though, but I doubt that has something to do with GCC. So could be version differences. I am using GCC version 4.4.5: "gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5) 4.4.5"

Answer (score 1):

The expression you are using as `Test_Function` argument is a type, not a function pointer. The function pointer is just the function's name:

```
Test_Function(Minimum);
```

Answer (score 0):

You tagged this `c`, so I take it you're using a C compiler (not C++) -- right?  In that case you need to either write `struct Node` in each declaration, or use a `typedef`.

Comment: Run your tap water on a lab for hallucinogenics.